# C# Syntax Error. Having trouble making an incremental counter in Unity for OnMouseDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, having a lot of issues trying to implement some code I'm working on in Unity. I want to have it so that when I click on the object, it will write to the Debug console a number, that increases by 5 each time it is clicked up to a max of 50.

But for some reason my script doesn't want to attach, I've got a syntax error that I can't quite figure out, does anyone have any ideas? Would really appreciate any help.

Here's my current code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Supercyl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int i = 5;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {


        if i >= 50;
             Debug.log(i);
             i = i + 5;


        {
            Debug.Log(i);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is probably a good time to find some introductory tutorials on C#.  Your `if` structure is entirely malformed.

Comment: [The `if` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-if-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error you are getting is most likely related to completely misformatted if statement. The correct syntax is

```
if (condition)
   {
     // code here
   }
```

Secondly, if you want to react to click on an object use IPointerClickHandler interface, from UnityEngine.EventSystems namespace.
Remember to add PhysicsRaycaster component to your camera if the object is not UI. The clicked object also needs to have a collider

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Supercyl : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    private int counter = 0;
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        counter += 5;
        Debug.Log($"Counter value {counter}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps for me to understand it a bit more at least, so... Using the PointerClickHandler would mean I can't use OnMouseDown, correct?

Comment: I was able to get it to compile properly and attach to my object, however, when I try to click on it it just prints the Else statement, and doesn't seem to want to print the counter. Any idea why this?

```
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {


        if (i >= 50)
        {
            i += 5;
            Debug.Log(i);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Wrong");
        }

}
    
```

Comment: @AlexWong what would happen for an i below 50? You wouldn't enter the 'if', so it wouldn't increase